# Jquery Hover Class Fade with Background Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following Jquery script below that adds a the .hover class on rollover and then removes it on rollout. Currently, the background (whether image or color) fades in and out nicely. However, I don't want the menu text to fade in and out.

I'm aware of the CSS3 fade transitions and the Jquery color plugins but would like to have the option of fading in image backgrounds as well (which is why I'd like to fade in a class rather than just background-color.) Any help would be most appreciated:)Thanks in advance.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Set the anchor link opacity to 0 and begin hover function
    $("#menu-sample-menu li a").hover(function () {

        //Fade to an opacity of 1 at a speed of 200ms
        $(this).fadeOut(0).addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);

        //On mouse-off
    }, function () {

        //Fade to an opacity of 0 at a speed of 100ms
        $(this).fadeOut(300)
            .queue(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover').fadeIn(0).dequeue()
        });

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<nav id="access">
    <ul id="menu-sample-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-198"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/health-care-professional/">Health Care Professional</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-197" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-197"><a href="demo/category/web-designer/">Web Designer</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-199" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-199"><a href="category/construction-worker/">Construction Worker</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Style

```
#access li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#access ul li:first-child {
    padding-left:0;
}

#access a {
    display:block;
    padding:15px 24px;
    color:#f0f0f0;
    text-decoration:none;

}

#menu-sample-menu li {
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #777;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
}

#menu-sample-menu li a.hover {
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: url(images/over.jpg);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/WjrnB/1/

Simply use:

```
#menu-sample-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: url(images/over.jpg);

}
```

instead of

```
#menu-sample-menu li a.hover {
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: url(images/over.jpg);

}
```

and add:

```
#menu-sample-menu li a {
    -khtml-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: i wish i could vote this a thousand times up. jQuery is not the answer to everything!

Comment: Thx for the response. I'm actually not looking to use CSS3 transitions because of lack of IE9 support. On a side note, does that CSS3 fade work with images as well as background-color?

Comment: with CSS3 transition, you can create a fade on anything. Altogether or on particular things within the element. As far as IE9 support, I wouldn't sweat it because it doesn't break anything, it just won't fade slowly. Everything else will work. The best advice you can get in cross-browser web-design, is that you design your projects so that they degrade gracefully. Take a look at this on transitions: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-fundametals-css-3-transitions/ and this for browser use: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: Thank you for the links and information. It was very informative and I know I'll be making more use of this as a substitute very soon. In the meantime, would you happen to know how to work the above Jquery so that it only animates the background-color or image?

Answer (score 0):

Xarcell's answer is probably the best simplicity-wise.  If you are looking to accomplish this with JavaScript, one option would be using [JQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/) which has addClass and removeClass functions which incorporate transitions.

Basically, the HTML and CSS is the same as above, but the JS would look as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//Set the anchor link opacity to 0 and begin hover function
$("#menu-sample-menu li a").hover(function () {
    //Fade 'hover' class in at 300ms
    $(this).addClass('hover', 300);
    //On mouse-off
}, function () {
        //Fade 'hover' class out at 300ms
        $(this).removeClass('hover', 300);
   });
});
```

And, of course, you would have to include JQuery-UI (I usually use Cloud Flair's CDNJS):

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js

Personally, I would use this method if I was already using JQuery-UI.  Otherwise, I would go with Xarcell's solution.